# How to show the file name in Progressbar for file uploading in Android?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar, android-file

I have to upload the file from my sdcard in android phone, I try to show the file name in textview from list of which is uploading in progress bar. I have added the code which i follow. but the result is not what i expected. Problem Scenario is the folder contains 20 music files, i have to show the 1 to 20 file names one by one in progressbar, but it show only the 20th file name in progressbar. kindly help me its my humble request. thanks in Advance.

**UploadFileSequnce.Java**

```
public class UploadFileSequnce extends Activity {

        ProgressBar pb;
        Dialog dialog;
        int downloadedSize = 0;
        int totalSize = 0;
        TextView cur_val;
        String fileName = "";

        String dwnload_file_path = "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0193/0692/products/mocg2smm0206.jpeg";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // showProgress(dwnload_file_path);
                    showFileProgress();
                    /*
                     * new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
                     * //downloadFile(); //loadFileNames(); } }).start();
                     */
                }
            });
        }

        void downloadFile() {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(dwnload_file_path);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                // connect
                urlConnection.connect();

                // set the path where we want to save the file
                File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                // create a new file, to save the downloaded file
                File file = new File(SDCardRoot, "downloaded_file.png");

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                // Stream used for reading the data from the internet
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // this is the total size of the file which we are downloading
                totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        pb.setMax(totalSize);
                    }
                });

                // create a buffer...
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bufferLength = 0;

                while ((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                    // update the progressbar //
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            pb.setProgress(downloadedSize);
                            float per = ((float) downloadedSize / totalSize) * 100;
                            cur_val.setText("Downloaded " + downloadedSize
                                    + "KB / " + totalSize + "KB (" + (int) per
                                    + "%)");
                        }
                    });
                }
                // close the output stream when complete //
                fileOutput.close();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // pb.dismiss(); // if you want close it..
                    }
                });

            } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
                showError("Error : MalformedURLException " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                showError("Error : IOException " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                showError("Error : Please check your internet connection " + e);
            }
        }

        void showError(final String err) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadFileSequnce.this, err, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }

        void showProgress(String file_path) {
            dialog = new Dialog(UploadFileSequnce.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Download Progress");

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            text.setText("Downloading file from ... " + file_path);
            cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
            cur_val.setText("Starting download...");
            dialog.show();

            pb = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(0);
            pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.green_progress));
        }

        void showFileProgress() {
            dialog = new Dialog(UploadFileSequnce.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
            dialog.setTitle("File Progress");
            // loadFileNames();

            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            text.setText("Upload file from ... " + loadFileNames());
            cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
            cur_val.setText("Starting Upload...");
            dialog.show();

            pb = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            pb.setProgress(0);
            pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.green_progress));
        }

        String loadFileNames() {
            // File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            // File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Download");
            String path = "storage/sdcard1/music mohan";
            File ff = new File(path);
            if (ff != null) {
                File yourDir = new File(ff, "mohan hits");
                for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                    System.out.println("Filename:" + f.getName());
                    if (f.isDirectory())
                        fileName = f.getName();


                }
            }
            return fileName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You mean `all 20 files update the same textview so naturally only the last name is visible` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response shark,Not at the time, file 2 name will show once the file1 will completed, is it possible to do?.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code:

```
loadFileNames();

    void showFileProgress() {
        dialog = new Dialog(UploadFileSequnce.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.myprogressdialog);
        dialog.setTitle("File Progress");

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        text.setText("Upload file from ... " + fileName);
        cur_val = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cur_pg_tv);
        cur_val.setText("Starting Upload...");
        dialog.show();

        pb = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        pb.setProgress(0);
        pb.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.green_progress));
    }

    String loadFileNames() {
        // File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        // File yourDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Download");
        String path = "storage/sdcard1/music mohan";
        File ff = new File(path);
        if (ff != null) {
            File yourDir = new File(ff, "mohan hits");
            for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                System.out.println("Filename:" + f.getName());
                if (f.isDirectory())
                    fileName = f.getName();


            }
            showFileProgress();
        }
        return fileName;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But the Code is not working, simply progressbar not showing.

Comment: sorry instead of String loadfileNames() try public void loadfileNames()